# Why friendly_id don't works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I have added gem

```
'friendly_id', '~> 5.1'
```

to my Gemfile and typed commands:

```
rails generate friendly_id 
rails generate migration add_slug_to_posts slug:string:uniq
```

Here is my model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged,
. . . 
end
```

and controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def show
    @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @postCreator = User.find(@post.user_id)
   end
. . .
end
```

When I try to load some post, I get an error. But through rails console all works fine. 
[image: this is what I get]

and

[image: error]

I have tried to restart server. No effect.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can yu post relevant view page code?

Comment: @Pavan sure  http://paste2.org/KFtXOVPd

Comment: bg_mi did you see the stack trace ? I suspect the mistake is in the line `User.find(@post.user_id)` , though I'm not sure

Comment: Which part of the code is taking you to `/posts/good-id`?

Comment: @Pavan  this 
<%= link_to excerpt(post.title, post.title[0], radius: 16), post_path(post) %>

Comment: Try `post_path(post.slug)` instead `post_path(post)`

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to this problem.

I fixed it just added `:finders` to `use:`

Now it looks this like:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :finders] 
. . . 
end
```

And also I removed `.friendly` from `Post.friendly.find(params[:id])` and using just

```
Post.find(params[:id])
```

I don't know how, but it helped me.

Hopefully it will be useful for someone.